# Getting specific index such students names from json data

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I am developing simple app in iOS that gets data web api my code returned json data correctly but when I want to specific for example student name from json returned null.
 Here is my data :

```
{
Sudent( 
{
    {"id":"20",
    "name":"Alan",
    "email":"simpl@gmail.com",
    "phone":"1234567890",
    "location":"London"},
 {  
"id":"40",
    "name":"John",
    "email":"simpl@gmail.com",
    "phone":"1234567890",
    "location":"usa"},
"id":"50",
    "name":"Nora",
    "email":"simpl@gmail.com",
    "phone":"1234567890",
    "location":"kenya"}, 

})}
```

Here my code that gets data as json and stored NSMutableArray named Student:

```
-(void)proxydidFinishLoadingData:(id)data InMethod:(NSString*)method
{
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"getstudentdata"]){

       defaultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
         [defaultDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil]];
         Student = [defaultDict objectForKey:@"data"];

    }
}
```

this codes it works ok and correctly and returned json data but the problem is when I want to get specific index such as names of students  it is not work it returns null value.
the code that does this work is here:

```
NSMutableDictionary *response = [[defaultDict valueForKey:@"data"] mutableCopy];
    NSString *name = [[response valueForKey:@"name"]];
   ];

      NSLog(@"%@" ,name);
```

Please help me this to get student names

Comment: It's unclear: What did you print exactly? Avoid using `valueForKey:`, I don't recommend it for beginners, use `objectForKey:` instead, and why the double brackets in `[[response valueForKey:@"name"]]`? What is `response` exactly in this case? I see an `NSArray` in your logq, but nothing about it.

Comment: first get NSArray of students then you will be able to get name from dictionary.

Comment: how to get please help me

Comment: @Mrdavidalan can you get data in your array?yes or no.

Comment: sorry this format is invalid.

Comment: yes I can get  data in my NSMutableDictionary *response variable. for example in above code when I check to display values of response  variable it works fine and display all my json data. but if I want to get specific data such us names of students it is not works it returns null

Comment: wait i update my answer.

Comment: From your response this is an `Array `of `Dictionary` So `[[studentData objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"name"]` should work for you.

Comment: I tried this , but it displays the fallowing the error NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x604000421fc0' please help this

Answer (score 0):

You are checking "name" key in "data" key, but in fact it is present in "Student" key.

Parse to Student object and using for loop get one by one "name" key value.

Use this site http://www.json4swift.com/ to create Model.(Just you have to Put JSON response here).

```
Var dataModelArray = [Your_Model_Type]()
if let data = data[“student”] as? [String: AnyObject]  {
  dataModelArray = Your_Model_type.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: data)
}
```

//And you will have array of data in your dataModelArray
//Example you can access like this

```
dataModelArray[0].name
```

Comment: can you help  me simple example example   I am new in ios

Comment: See my edited answer... That will give you hint and thats perfect process

Comment: There is no `swift` tag in the question.